# Take in user input and search through arrays

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a code that reads in from a text file and prints out the information there as an array in the terminal. I have gotten this part working. It reads in a music file with multiple albums and the tracks they contain from a file, then displays the albums information to the Terminal. Now, I want the user to be able to search for a track by inputting the track name and display a message saying that user-selected track is playing. I have also written a search function that is able to take in user input and check if the user input is present in the array. How can I modify this search function to now search for a track and display a message saying that user-selected track is playing?

text file

```
2
Greatest Hits
Neil Diamond
1
3
Crackling Rose
sounds/01-Cracklin-rose.wav
Soolaimon
sounds/06-Soolaimon.wav
Sweet Caroline
sounds/20-Sweet_Caroline.wav
Billboard 2019 Rock
Various Artist
4
3
Track 1
sounds/album2/track1.mp3
Track 2
sounds/album2/track2.mp3
Track 3
sounds/album2/track3.mp3
```

search function I have written before:

```
def search_for_track_name(tracks, search_string)
  index = 0
  found_index=-1

  while (index<tracks.length)
    if (tracks[index].name==search_string)
        found_index=index


    end
    index+=1
    end 
    return found_index
    end
```

Code I am trying to write:

```
def play_selected_track(albums)
    # ask user to enter ID number of an album in the albums-list
   puts "Enter album id"
    album_id =
    # check if the album_id is found - then
    # ask user to enter ID number of a track in the tracks-list of that album
    track_id = ??
    # check if the track_id is found - then
    # dipslay 'The selected track [] is now playing...'
    # ??
end
```

```
def main()
    music_file = File.new("album.txt", "r")
    album = read_album(music_file)
    print_album(album)

    music_file.close()
    puts "Enter the track name you wish to find: "
    search_name = gets.chomp

    index = search_for_track_name(album.tracks, search_name)
    if index > -1
        puts "Found " + album.tracks[index].name+ "\n at " + index.to_s()
    else
        puts "Entry not Found"
    end
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to search through an array in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717147/trying-to-search-through-an-array-in-ruby)

Comment: "How can I modify this search function to now search for a track and display a message saying that user-selected track is playing?" => Have you considered implementing your change outside the search function?

Comment: The search function looks good to me. Unless I am missing something I would expect the interaction to be (1) search the track and (2) select the track